# Oracle update table with the value from another database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sql-update

In one db i have table `PRODUCTS` with columns `NAME` and `TECHNICAL_NAME`.

In second database I have table `TEMP_PRODUCTS` with columns `NAME` (that corresponds to column `NAME` of the table `PRODUCTS` from the 1st db) and `TECHNICAL_NAME` that is `null` and that should be updated with the corresponding `TECHNICAL_NAME` values from 1st db.

So I should do `UPDATE table TEMP_PRODUCTS` by using `JOIN` with columns `NAME`?

I would like to avoid solution with exporting table from 1st bd and importing it to the 2nd db.

How can I do this?

Comment: :You need to create a db link first between 1st db and 2nd db .And then join the table ,based on name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Creating the DB Link only we can access the one DB objects from another DB.

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK db1_link 
   CONNECT TO <User Name> IDENTIFIED BY <pwd>
   USING 'db2';
```

-- db2 means Service Name for exp products db

Then Update Statement

```
UPDATE temp_products tp
  SET technical_name=
    (SELECT technical_name FROM products@db1_link p
      WHERE tp.name = p.name)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming:

- both `NAME` columns are `UNIQUE`;
- you have a [database link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm) in `db2` pointing to `db1`.

```sql
UPDATE temp_products tp
  SET technical_name=
    (SELECT technical_name FROM products@db1 p
      WHERE tp=name=p.name)
```

Comment: yes names are unique. How do you mean 'you have database link in bd2 pointing to bd1'? After executing your sql i get SQL Error: ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found
02019. 00000 -  "connection description for remote database not found"

Comment: @gospodin As if you have done something like this before: `CREATE DATABASE LINK db1 CONNECT TO usr IDENTIFY BY pwd USING connection_string`. [Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm)

Comment: Read this to understand database links http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm, don't forget to add a `SET TRANSACTION` before the update so you can test the result and `ROLLBACK` when it didn't work as you desire or `COMMIT` when the result is good

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute the below query in `db2` ,where `temp_product` table lies,and db link `db1` on the same database `db2`,to connect `db1`.

```
   MERGE temp_products tp
     USING products@db1 pp
     ON(tp.name = pp.name)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET tp.technical_name = pp.technical_name;
```

You need to create a db link in database db2,so that you can connect to db1 ,to acces product table.
Please find the syntax for creating db link

```
CREATE [PUBLIC] DATABASE LINK <link_name>
CONNECT TO <user_name>
IDENTIFIED BY <password>
USING '<service_name>';
```